# How to build a tree select box ui in jsp with js, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, tree, html-select

First, What I am trying to do is build a UI like below.

[image]

I have data like below format ...

```
{'id' : '0001', 'name' : 'products', 'parents' : '*'}
```

I have tried this with `<optgroup>` but it does not looks like :<
Currently, I do not have any idea how to start this.

To do this, I got several questions.

1. What should I call this type of UI? (terminology)
2. Is there any libraries which implements this spec?
3. A sample code might be great help :D (It will be the best if it uses bootstrap, but it still be great without bootstrap)

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Your expectation only needs logic. Best if your try it yourself or make an online demo for it with your json inputs. Bootstrap navigation are available once your search it. But you need your logic to create ul li from your json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term that calling this type of ui is

> combotree

I have applied it from jquery-easy-ui
http://www.jeasyui.com/

caution : This library build unwanted UI automatically, so if you need to customize set `!important` css attributes.